# Calculate perc in Pandas Dataframe based on rows having a specific condition for each distinct value in column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with sample values as given below

`

```
col1   col2 
A     ['1','2','er'] 
A     [] 
B     ['3','4','ac'] 
B     ['5'] 
C     []
```

`

I want to calculate the percentage of total number of rows for each value in col1 against total number of rows in col2 that are not empty list.

I am able to do it if there is a single value in col1. I am looking for a solution to do this iteratively. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need compare length of lists greater like `0`, convert to number and athen aggregate `mean`:

```
df1 = df['col2'].str.len().gt(0).view('i1').groupby(df['col1']).mean().reset_index(name='%')
print (df1)
  col1    %
0    A  0.5
1    B  1.0
2    C  0.0
```

Comment: it worked. thanks. I also want to have the % of each element in the list in Col2 for each value of col2. i.e % of 1 for A and % of ac for B.